# CMS uses jquery 1.7, theme uses jQuery 1.6 == conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been given a theme to implement into a cms.

The theme uses jQuery 1.6 and has no javascript errors.

The CMS (concrete5) uses jQuery 1.7.1 and has no javascript errors.

When I merge the theme into the CMS, I drop the include to jQuery (since I was to avoid including jQuery twice) and now I am getting the following errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function (ccm.app.js line 1 --> ccm.app.js is part of the CMS javascript).
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function (page controls menu.js).
```

The script src references are in this order:

```
- jQuery
- ccm.app.js (CMS)
- page controls menu.js (CMS)
- custom.js (my theme)
```

I realize that this isn't a lot of code to look at and troubleshoot, but does anyone know the differences between jQuery 1.6 and jQuery 1.7 that **might** be causing this kind of error?

Comment: Sounds like they're both still being included after all. Or neither is. ;-)

Comment: Hmm I just doublechecked that, but it looks like it's only getting included once

Comment: If you open up your dev tools (F12 in your browser) go to the console and enter `$` and hit enter, what does it return?

Comment: Good point. I just tried that it says undefined.

Comment: What about if you put in `jQuery`?

Comment: I get "function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of jQuery you're using isn't assigning the shortcut `$`. You can either change what you're referencing to script wise to one that is assigning the shortcut, or, immediately after importing jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$ = jQuery;
</script>
```

Comment: This points out what is wrong but in my particular case I can't use it without messing with the CMS php (which I can't do in case of upgrade)

Comment: Is the jQuery file you're importing edited at all? It wouldn't make sense for the `$` to not be assigned.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking too. Obviously it's using the $ without a problem until I include my custom.js file

Comment: My custom.js file had a lot of jQuery.noConflict() wrappers, I just removed them and this removes the $ error...but now I have other errors I'm wrapped up in fixing ;-(

Comment: Well, the CMS should be using `jQuery` instead of `$` because of potential compatibility issues with other libraries. But if you can't change the code you can't change the code... good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The answer above gets to the root of what was wrong, but I thought I would just mention this part in case any one else has the same problem.

For me, in my custom.js file, I have jQuery noConflict wrappers around each little bit of jQuery:

```
jQuery.noConflict()(function($){
   $(document).ready(function() {
     // some jQuery javascript here     

   });
});
```

Changing it back to just:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     // some jQuery javascript here     

   });
```

Got rid of the problem I was having.